# Why do some conferences with double blind review ask for author names when submitting the paper for review?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, anonymity

I wonder why some conferences with double blind review ask for author names when submitting the paper for review. Why not asking for author information once the paper has been accepted?

Answer (score 18):

Likely so they can track the papers internally by author. It prevents, for example, a submission being sent out to a reviewer who is on the paper.'

Double-blind just means that the reviewers are unknown to the author, and the author is unknown to the reviewers. It doesn't say anything about the conference organizers/editorial staff.

Comment: Thanks. Why not asking reviewers to list their paper submission number(s), if they've submitted anything? Is there any other use of the author information by the conference organizers/editorial staff?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt An extra layer of security? It allows *them* to check, rather than relying on the authors reporting. I've been an author on a conference submission that I was only faintly aware of what was happening - relying on me to remember to ask for the number, and then report it, is less reliable than saying "Don't send this to Fomite, he's an author."

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In my discipline, at least, you wouldn't send a paper to a colleague of an author i.e. somebody at the same institution. So you'd also need to know all the submission numbers for any colleagues who might have submitted to the same journal or conference.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt cfr is right - conflict-of-interest. Some conferences I review for present a list of all authors who have submitted, without their submission info, so I can mark anyone who I have a COI with without seeing what they submitted. Useful for e.g. making sure I don't review my Ph.D adviser's work!

Answer (score 5):

1. So that the Program Chair can check for conflicts of interest beyond what authors may have reported.
2. So that new authors don't pop up or disappear magically once a paper is accepted.

Comment: Thanks. Why would new authors pop up or disappear magically once a paper is accepted?

Comment: If authors change after the paper is accepted, there's a chance that it may impact the integrity of the review process adversely. Other situations that author disclosure seeks to curb include, for example, gift authorship.

Comment: Authors might disappear if attempted plagiarism is discovered, also.

Answer (score 0):

A sudden thought about one of the reasons for this just crosses my mind. Doing so also prevents authors from changing the author list. Although technically, one can encrypt the author names without exposing the names to the program committee.